# How can i filter my firebase document multiple filelds for quiz application?

Tags: api, filtering, algolia

I try to create an ordinary or unordinary quiz with a speciel filter which is include familiarty, category, subcategory, diffculty etc. but I cant find any api for filter my question.

I am using algolia for filter but Algolia doesnt allow randomize query because Algolia design for search so every time algolia return best result thus I cant create custom quiz. Can you suggest an api for my application?